# data attribute assigned to variables in global scope doesn't work on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I load html content into DOM on the fly like this I have no problem at all, all the script works.

**1)**

```
 $('body').append('<div id="ckit" class="layout-compact is-hiddenx"\
         data-ckit-compact style="">........./div>');
```

But I don't wanna do that, instead I want to get the html from another page like this and this is where the problem occurs..

**2)**

```
$.get( "/plugins/system/conversekit/conversekit/index.php", function( data ) {
       $('body').append(data);
    }, "html" );
```

This the script responsible to handle the events: (doesn't work in ajax call as no **2)**)

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Toggle to full view
        var toggleCkitOn = $('[data-ckit-toggle-on]');
        var ckitFull = $('[data-ckit-full]');
        var ckitCompact = $('[data-ckit-compact]');
        var ckitIframe = $('[data-ckit-iframe]');

         toggleCkitOn.on('click', function(e) {
             $(ckitFull).removeClass("is-hidden");
             $(ckitCompact).addClass("is-hidden");
             $('body').addClass("disable-scrolling");
             $("html").css({"height": "100%", "overflow": "hidden"});
             $("body").css({"position": "relative"});
             e.preventDefault();
         });
```

I found that the data-attributes assigned to variables unable to work properly. So I came up with this and this works.

```
 $("body").on("click", toggleCkitOn, function(e) { 

                 $('[data-ckit-full]').removeClass("is-hidden");
                 $('[data-ckit-compact]').addClass("is-hidden");
                 $('body').addClass("disable-scrolling");
                 $("html").css({"height": "100%", "overflow": "hidden"});
                 $("body").css({"position": "relative"});
                 e.preventDefault();
            } );
.........
.........
```

Please compare how these things are changed..

`$(ckitFull)` **changed to** `$('[data-ckit-full]')`

**OR else,**

if I declare the variables inside the function scope it works, but again its not a proper way.

```
$("body").on("click", toggleCkitOn, function(e) { 

   var toggleCkitOn = $('[data-ckit-toggle-on]');
    var ckitFull = $('[data-ckit-full]');
    var ckitCompact = $('[data-ckit-compact]');
    var ckitIframe = $('[data-ckit-iframe]');

 $(ckitFull).removeClass("is-hidden");
        $(ckitCompact).addClass("is-hidden");
        $('body').addClass("disable-scrolling");
        $("html").css({"height": "100%", "overflow": "hidden"});
        $("body").css({"position": "relative"});
             e.preventDefault();
        } );
```

But why unable to use `$(ckitFull)`? It wouldn't be proper way if I didn't assign them into variables. SO how can I  fix this issue?

Comment: First when you assign `ckitFull` the element does not exist yet. You will need to assign it after it's created. Second, `ckitFull` is already a jquery object, you don't need to wrap it in `$()` again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem with **2)** is this:

In your events-handling script, you grab references to the elements you want right when the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Toggle to full view
    var toggleCkitOn = $('[data-ckit-toggle-on]');
    var ckitFull = $('[data-ckit-full]');
    var ckitCompact = $('[data-ckit-compact]');
    var ckitIframe = $('[data-ckit-iframe]');

    // ... other stuff omitted
```

When you modify the DOM directly, your content is added quickly enough that the `document`'s `ready` event can see it. However, when you use an AJAX call to populate the page, `onready` is fired *before* the response is received from the server. No elements are found matching your special attributes, because *they haven't been added to the DOM yet*.

I would suggest setting the variables and adding the `click` listener in the `success` handler for jQuery's [`get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method.

```
$.get( "/plugins/system/conversekit/conversekit/index.php", function( data ) {
   $('body').append(data);

   // Create vars here, and add click handler here
}, "html" );
```

Comment: is there anywhere I can only declare variables only in the event handler script? I'm creating this as independent plugin so I cant declare it in get call

Answer (score 0):

Use proper event delegation by only passing selector as target. You are trying to pass a jQuery object as target and it doesn't include elements that don't exist when that object was created

```
$("body").on("click", '[data-ckit-toggle-on]', function(e) { 

     var toggleCkitOn = $(this);// I am assuming there is only one such element...otherwise use selector
     .....
```

Comment: no there are other variables too... can yu show me how to use the selector

Comment: other variables or other elements with that attribute? All the other variables you have would be the same...this would be only one that could be `this` because it is the actual target of the click

Comment: You could just keep all the rest of your code the same to avoid confusion for now also...but use the selector as target of delegation as on the first line

Answer (score 0):

This when and then solved my issue

```
jQuery(function($){

    var getHtml = $.get( "/plugins/system/conver/conver/index.php", function( data ) {$('body').append(data);}, "html" );    

    $.when(getHtml).done(function() {
       $.getScript("/plugins/system/conver/conver/js/script.js");
    });

})
```